# Using bootstrap css to display html components

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I trying to put few html elements to show them properly. But could not get how to place them inline.

CODEPEN : [CODEPEN  DEMO](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/AhEje)

```
<div class="jumbotron">  
    <ul class="media-list">
        <li class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                <img class="media-object" src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg" height="35">
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h6 class="media-heading"> This is small description of image </h6>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>  
        <h6>Wat more? ....... </h6>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="badge pull-right">42</span>
                        Only value
                    </a>
                </li>

                <span> Above code should look like this </span>
                <img src="http://snag.gy/cPTCL.jpg">
```

Comment: What elements do you want to change their css?

Comment: Oh.. You are doing it in wrong way. You need some basic knowledge of how things work. May be some online tuts would help you.

Comment: @SurjithSM: can you please suggest me source?

Comment: @marios: all elements. I have selected pieces. I want combine them all and want to create image in the bottom

Comment: @user3121782 http://www.codecademy.com/ http://teamtreehouse.com might help you how to use semantic tags.